# Iterating through a gzipped object in Python with strings, not bytes

Tags: python, gzip

Depending on the extension of files, I use a different opener with context manager like so:

```
if args.vcf_in.endswith(".gz"):
    dopenf = gzip.open
    mode = "rb"
else:
    openf = open
    mode = "rt"
```

Unfortunately, when I try to iterate through the object in one case it is bytes and in another string, and the code fails:

```
with openf(args.vcf_in, mode) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        count += 1
        print(line)
        if line.startswith("#"):
```

Is there way to iterate through a gzipped file so that the outputted lines are strings? I know I can check if they are bytes and decode them but I am curious is there a better way using the opener, or io package.

Thanks!

Comment: Binary files don't have the concept of lines, so your code is not usable with the *.gz* files.

Comment: Can you please show a minimal example of what you are doing and the desired output? It is unclear under which conditions you receive bytes. In the first case, you are wrapping the file in a TextIOWrapper (which provides strings), and in the second case you are opening in text mode (which provides strings).

Comment: Sorry, the first case was my botched attempt at reading it. I edited the code above to use only gzip.open. I basically need a way to iterate through a large gzipped file line by line.

Comment: @CindyAlmighty Try `dopenf = gzip.open()` or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I've misunderstood something here but if your gzipped file is a text file, you should be able to simply call gzip.open() with mode='r' (not 'rb') in place of the standard open(). There is no need for all the io classes.